# From where do you start counting distance when you have natural reach?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranged-attack

I encountered an odd situation.

I am playing a naturally large(tall) character so I have a natural reach of 10. My character is also based using a bow for ranged attacks, I also have [point blank shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat---final) so when what I am attacking is within 30 feet I get some bonuses. So the question is, where do you start counting distance from? Is it from the edge of your personal space square or from the edge of your natural reach square?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Point Blank Shot doesn't care about your reach.

Point Blank Shot, and anything that counts range from you, counts that range from the center of a square within your space.  None of the rules relating to range talk about your reach at all, so your reach isn't counted when you're calculating distance to your target.

The rules about attacking targets using reach state:

> Creatures that take up more than 1 square typically have a natural reach of 10 feet or more, meaning that they can reach targets even if they aren't in adjacent squares.

There's no mention there of treating distant creatures as if they're closer to you, just that you can now reach creatures that are closer with your melee attacks.  There's no mention at all in the reach rules of ranged attacks, so having reach greater than five feet doesn't effect ranged attacks at all.

Comment: I had the wrong feat listed, it has been updated

Comment: @Fering I updated my answer to reference the correct feat, but it doesn't really change the answer.

Comment: I was under the impression that larger ranged creatures were not common so it might have been left out.

Comment: Well, "larger ranged creatures" include dragons, demons, and anything else that's Large and has spellcasting, so it's not exactly rare.  If they intended large size to do something relating to range calculation, then they probably would have said that somewhere.

Comment: The *Rules Compendium* for *D&D 3.5* says, "For ranged attacks and other effects that originate from a creature, the point of origin is any corner of any square that the creature occupies" (80). Did *Pathfinder* really change that to any creature's square's *center*?

Comment: I can't seem to find the reference that I remember on the subject, so I can't say for certain.  Does it really matter?

Comment: My gut tells me the *numbers* will be identical (a mathematician would know better, though), but it's weird that determining distance uses a different *process* from, for example, determining [line of sight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Line-of-Sight).